# scope variable gets undefined inside function - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to call a function with scope variables. Its getting undefined inside function there.

```
setstates($scope.events.myevent,bannerslidesmyevent,$scope.eventPlus,$scope.myeventtime,myeventcurrenttime);
```

Definition:

```
function setstates(event,banner,eventplus,eventtime,currenteventtime)
{
  if(event ===null || event ==='null' || event ===undefined)
    {
        banner.goto(2);
        eventplus = -1;
    }
    else if(event[0] === '+')
    {
        banner.goto(2);
        eventplus = event.split('+')[1];
    }
    else 
    {
        currenteventtime.setHours(event.split(':')[0]);
        currenteventtime.setMinutes(event.split(':')[1]);
        eventtime = currenteventtime;
    }
}
```

Issue is with `$scope.myeventtime` ,which is `eventtime` inside function, getting undefined.

HTML:

```
<timepicker class="timepicker" ng-model="myeventtime" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
```

The time is not being set.

Comment: are you saying eventtime/$scope.myeventtime is defined when the method is called but undefined inside the method? at what point is it undefined as you are setting a value to it at the end of the function?

Comment: When function is called, it does not set the time. @atmd

Comment: I cant see $scope.myeventtime in your code. if you have declared $scope.myeventtime, than you need to assign value to $scope.myeventtime itself, not eventtime.

Comment: $scope.myeventtime up there where setstates is being called. I have to set hours and minutes to that `ng-model="myeventtime"`

Comment: when I `alert(currenteventtime);`  its showing the time, but not being assigned to `eventtime`

Comment: you need to declare these $scope variable outside function call also. As you  difference is actual and formal parameter is,  A change in formal arguments would not be reflected in the actual arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the pointing value of a local variable `eventtime` not the original scope variable.
Since this is a date object you can do that instead:

```
eventtime.setHours(event.split(':')[0]);
eventtime.setMinutes(event.split(':')[1]);
```

this will act upon the original scope param as `setHours` and `setMinutes` are methods of the original object.

**Edit**: Just realized you are attempting to set both `currenteventtime` and `eventtime` to the same value. you would need to run `setHours` and `setMinutes`  on both then

Comment: can you create a pkunker with the problem?